# Jquery Flexslider with Sliding effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$('.flexslider.wsc_banner4519').each(function () {
    var _this = this;
    $('.slides > li', this).hide();
    $(this).flexslider($.extend({}, {
        animation: 'fade',
        slideshow: false,
        slideshowSpeed: 7000,
        pagination: true,
        directionNav: false,
        animationDuration: 600
    }, {
        before: function (slider) {
            var descs = $(_this).next('.descriptions').find('article');
            if (slider.animatingTo != slider.currentSlide && descs.length >= slider.slides.length) {
                descs.filter(':visible').fadeOut(slider.vars.animationDuration / 2, function () {
                    descs.eq(slider.animatingTo).fadeIn(slider.vars.animationDuration / 2);
                });
            }
        }
    })).hover(function () {
        $('.flex-direction-nav', this).stop(true).fadeTo(100, 1);
    }, function () {
        $('.flex-direction-nav', this).stop(true).fadeTo(100, 0);
    });
});
});
```

I am using flexslider(converted to double slider).Here both have fade-out effect.
I want image to be fade out and text to be sliding.

http://demo2.websitescreative.com/responsive/Features/sliderwithtext.aspx

Like this demo I have done. I want to change this into the effect I described above.
PLEASE Help.

Comment: Do you have any code you've written so far?

Comment: user animated.css https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: yes @nfn neil  
I have the function updated in the question